# In IE elements are get hide then after hover on them they get visible

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I am working with IE11. After loading my website elements like checkbox, radio button, drop down arrow get automatically hidden then after hover on them they get visible then after click anywhere in page they again get hide. All this element are present and style are applied tested with developer tool but still they was giving problem. Then after check "use software rendering instead of gpu rendering" option from settings->Internet option->Advanced->"use software rendering instead of gpu rendering" everything got ok. Now my website element not getting hide all style applied perfectly. But I doesn't understand why this happen? How this setting fixed issues. Please any idea help!